# Slow JSON parsing using iOS' NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios, swift, performance, instruments, foundation

I'm seeing performance issues when parsing large JSON using iOS Foundation's `NSJSONSerialization`. The JSON is roughly:

```
{
    "things": [
        { "id": 123, "name": "Foo", "weight": 12.34, ... }
        { "id": 456, "name": "Bar", "weight": 56.78, ... }
        ...
    ]
}
```

There are approximately 1000 things, with each thing having about about 50 name/value pairs.

The parsing code is approximately:

```
let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])
let jsonDict = json as! [String : AnyObject]
let things = jsonDict["things"] as! [[String : AnyObject]]
for thing in things {
    ...
}
```

Profiling with Instruments, the majority of the time is spent on the second cast (`json as! [[String : AnyObject]]`), On an iPhone 6 it takes 0.75 sec, on an iPad 4 (32-bit) it takes almost 3 seconds.

[image]

Is this just a function of how much data there is? It does after all, have to convert the entire JSON hierarchy into a Dictionary (although I'm surprised the time is spent in the casting and not `JSONObjectWithData`). Since the JSON is so flat, perhaps I should write my own SAX style parsing.

Comment: If it's slow then parse it on a background thread using `NSOperationQueue` or GCD. Also try to avoid force unwrapping / casting things :)

Comment: Any particular reason to do the cast? I believe you can still access the data structure directly after de-serialization.

Comment: @AndrewCarter I already have it running in the background, forced unwarp/cast is just for brevity of the example

Comment: @zcui93 The return type of `JSONObjectWithData` is AnyObject, how would I access it as an array or dictionary?